# Reflect camera in a plane

Tags: c++, reflection, matrix, camera

I have a camera, which is defined through an up vector, a position and a reference point (camera looks at this point). Furthermore I can calculate the view direction, of course.
Now I tried to reflect this camera in a plane (e.g. z = 0). My first attempt was to reflect every single vector in the plane with the belonging reflection matrix and looked like this:

```
mat4 mReflection = mat4(1, 0, 0, 0,
                        0, 1, 0, 0,
                        0, 0, -1, 0,
                        0, 0, 0, 1);
up = mReflection * up;
position = mReflection * position;
lookAt = mReflection * lookAt;
```

But this didn't work very well and I don't know why. What is wrong with this method?

Comment: Can you try the following just to be sure this doesn't have anything to do with the matrix: `up.z = -up.z; position.z = -position.z; lookAt.z = -lookAt.z;`

Comment: If I do it like you told I get the same results. I just think that the idea I had is just wrong but I don't know why.